# Why the need for a reboot with new HDD dock?

Tags: hard-drive, dock

Why is it necessary to reboot the computer for the OS to see a new HDD dock with a new HDD attached?

Background for the question:

I recently purchased a new 3TB HDD. When docking it in my old HDD dock, I ran into the problem that gparted reported the drive as being only 746GB or so. After some searching on the internet, I figured out that my old HDD docking stations only support drives up to 2TB. So I ran to the shop and bought a new dock which explicitly support drives up to 4TB. I plugged the power, plugged the USB, and inserted my 3TB drive into the dock. I fired gparted, but, horror!, gparted didn't see the drive at all. I looked at the box of the dock and saw that it supported USB 3.0 while my mainboard only supports USB 2.0. I was confused because I thought the newest USB version was backward compatible. I ran back to the shop and explained my problem. They assured that, as I thought, USB 3.0 is backward compatible with 2.0 and regardless of what my mainboard supports, it should be able to read it (albeit at USB 2.0 speed, obviously). They asked me whether I used windows XP, Vista or Windows 7. I said I use Linux. They said: "Haha!, there's the problem: on the box of the docking station, it doesn't say it supports Linux!". I thought: "F*** You!" and said: "The problem is *not* the Linux OS, as I am certain that it supports 4TB drives, USB 3.0 and this since much longer than windows has, and if I were to limit my hardware purchases to items which officially support linux (as printed on the box), I wouldn't be able to purchase any hardware at all!". So, they advised me to reboot my computer to see if my OS would see the new docking station and the HDD within it. I thanked them, went home, and tried to reboot the computer, and, indeed, gparted now saw the full 3TB of the new HDD! :)

Now, I have been using Linux for 13 years, and I have long lost the habit of rebooting the computer after installing new software and new USB hardware. I was sceptical that simply rebooting the OS would fix my problem, but it did. The question now is: why?

Comment: You don't always have automounting of drives - have you made sure it turned up on /dev, and have you tried mounting it manually?

Comment: You'll find that USB-over-SCSI (which a new USB 3.0 dock might be using) is quite new and not necessarily well-supported. Don't rule out your OS as the issue just yet. (The Linux driver was apparently listed as broken until Sept 2013, so you *might* get lucky with a kernel/distro upgrade, but don't count on it.) Though it supposedly works on XP... perhaps it drops back to Bulk-Only-Transfer when it needs to, but Linux's 'broken' driver is preventing that?

Comment: @Bob: thanks. I think you are right and the problem is with the dock and its driver. See comment to Braiam's answer. Please, post your comment as an Answer, with more info on how to identify USB-over-SCSI hardware. A distro upgrade is planned but will have to wait a few more weeks. Thanks.

Comment: @augustin Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with hardware detection in Linux to give a complete answer. Anyone else (including you) can feel free to turn that comment into a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I just found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI#Operating_system_support

Answer (score 1):

Well, you ask "Why you had to reboot to make sure the module is loaded". Lets remember that through Linux doesn't need reboot for most of operations there are still modules out in the wild that still doesn't behave correctly (I'm thinking about some VM software that if you don't restart it wouldn't work at all), with hardware sometimes it doesn't initialize correctly if isn't loaded at boot, etc.

Through you really trust Linux to comply with true Plug&Play, is difficult to really get all the hardware and corner cases such as yours. It would be interesting to see the dmesg output when you plugged the drive but I doubt you have it around anymore.

Comment: Thanks. +1. See Bob's comment below my question. I think the problem is with the dock itself. I couldn't plug&play a 2TB drive that is properly recognized as soon as I insert it in my old docks. I still have the dock and the drive: what would you like to see? Do you mean the content of /var/log/dmesg ?

Comment: Yeah, if you plug the drive it most likely reveal what is wrong and maybe it could be fixed.